# multipart form validation

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

So I have a multipart form that has fields for text, integers and file uploads.
I can use dataAnnotations and validationMessageFor for the text and int fields, but not for the file upload.
So I implemneted the following code to validate the file uploads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $("#Error").hide();
          var pdfFile = '<%=Model.PdfFile %>';
          if (pdfFile == null || pdfFile1 == "") {
              $("#Submit").click(function() {
                  var ext = $('#File').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
                  var file = $('#File').val();
                  if ((!file || ext != 'pdf')) {
                      $('#Error').show();
                      return false;
                  }
                  return true;
              });
          }
      });
```

This code works great, as far as I can tell at this point, but it executes before the checks on the other fields, so it looks sloppy.
In other words, if the user has multiple errors on the form when they click submit, 
The validation message for the file upload appears, but not for the other fields.
If the user then uploads a valid file and clicks submit again, then the validation messages for the other fields appear.  Sloppy.
So I tried implementing jQuery validation for the textboxes as well, but for some reason this doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $("#captionVal").hide();
          $("#Submit").click(function () {
              var caption = $("#Caption").val();
             if (!caption || caption == "") {
                  $("#captionVal").show();
                  return false;
              }
              return true;

          });
      });
```

It seems it always reads the field as null, so it never returns true.

I tried adding

```
$("Caption").change(function() {
```

as well as

```
$("#Caption").bind(function() {
```

in front of the if statement, but to no avail.

I also tried using the jQuery validation with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $("#term").validate();
      });
```

But that did nothing at all (perhaps I just don't understand how to use the plugin?)

So my question is, how can I validate the textboxes?
Really all I need to do is make sure they are not empty, and if they are display an error label (not a popup) on the submit click
Or how can I use the validation plugin?  I've downloaded the .zip file and added(& referenced) the .validate.js file, but the 
.validate method doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: This sentence concerns me: _"I've downloaded the `.zip` file and added the `.validate.js` file..."_  - specifically just mentioning the zip file seems to imply that you did not also **un-zip** the JS file.  (after all, how you obtained the plugin should be irrelevant.)  I could be wrong in my interpretation.  Are  you looking at the console and seeing any errors?

Comment: @Sparky672 I think you're reading too much into that...

Comment: @Terry, Maybe, but at least let the OP correct me, after all I did say, _"I could be wrong in my interpretation"_.  (See OP's first comment on the answer, _"At the risk of sounding really dumb, I think I may not understand how to install the plugin properly."_)

Comment: @Sparky672 Terry's right.  I was just referencing the wrong js file (jquery-1.7.2.js instead of jquery.js).  But thanks for asking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your form fields have a name attribute, and that you are specifying validation rules either during the plugin declaration or via the built in class feature.

Also you can add a custom validation method right into the plugin and use it like the ones already built in:

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="path/to/jquery.js">
   <script src="path/to/jquery-validator.js">
   <script>
    // Add a custom method for file validation (going off your logic - haven't tested)
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("file", function(value, element) { 
        var ext = value.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        return (!value || ext != 'pdf');
    }, "Please make sure your file has a valid PDF extension");

    // This will make the form pass all validation checks on submit and 
    //  display errors if any occur
    $('#myForm').validate();
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="myForm">
      <input type="text" name="email" class="required email" />
      <input type="text" name="username" class="required" />
      <input type="text" name="file" class="required file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit form and get your ass validated!" />
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Custom validation method reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage

**Edit**:  Just noticed the plugin has a file extension validating method built in:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept#extension

**Edit 2:** Here's how you can validate without using a custom method (using the one I just found built in):

```
<input type="text" name="file" />

    $('#myForm').validate({
         rules: {
            file: {
                required: true,
                accept: "pdf"
             }
         }
    });
```

Comment: At the risk of sounding really dumb, I think I may not understand how to install the plugin properly.  And I get an error on class="required" that it's an unknown CSS class.

Comment: Ok I updated with everything you need to make the validate plugin work (in the appropriate order).  Not sure what is saying "unknown CSS class", CSS classes are never supposed to be validated against anything.

Comment: @Jeff, What Terry just said.  You couldn't possibly be getting an error about an unknown CSS class.  You can use any class name whether it's defined or not... you'd never see an error.  What exactly is giving that error?

Comment: I guess it's just reSharper, disregard.

Comment: @Terry, Thanks for the response.  I was able to get .validate() working in a test project with a simple form but for some reason not in my actual project with a more complex form.  Probably some small difference that my eyes aren't picking up.  At any rate, I've managed to fix the logic in the broken code from my original question (I was referencing the input id, not the name).  Marking this as answer nonetheless, as it is certainly a valid solution and may help others. Thanks again!